# git throws : "FATAL: You must specify http proxy server"

Tags: git

```
# git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6
Cloning into linux-2.6...
FATAL: You must specify http proxy server
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

what is the error its been talking about ?  though I have the proxy set.

```
# env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://<ip-address>:80
GIT_PROXY_COMMAND=/root/bin/git-tunnel
```

however if I use http:// (instead of git://) it works.

Comment: Answering my own question.

Per git code it was looking for 'HTTP_PROXY' not 'http_proxy', damn I need more coffee.
set the following and it works like charm

    # export HTTP_PROXY=http://<IP>:80

Comment: sonu - feel free to add (and accept) that as an answer for others who may run into the same issue :)

Comment: This is very confusing: Git does not use http_proxy (nor HTTP_PROXY) for git native protocol (which is what "git://..."-URLs mean). 
Maybe you had it the other way around? http:// needed the proxy, git:// worked as is